# Callbacks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, callback

I want to have a library that will have a function in it that accepts an object for it's parameter.

With this object I want to be able to call a specified function when X is finished. The function that will be called is to be specified by the caller, and X will be done and monitored by the library.

How can I do this?

For reference I'm using C# and .NET 3.5

Comment: I suspect your answer contains degates, events, or both.  However, after reading your question a couple times, I'm unable to wrap my head around what you are asking.

Comment: Here's a sample http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/there-are-lots-of-things-that-take-long.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Two options for you:

1. Have the function accept a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.8) ([`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) for a callback that doesn't return anything, [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) for one that does) and use an anonymous delegate or Lambda Expression when calling it.
2. Use an interface

### Using a delegate/lambda

```
public static void DoWork(Action processAction)
{
  // do work
  if (processAction != null)
    processAction();
}

public static void Main()
{
  // using anonymous delegate
  DoWork(delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Completed"); });

  // using Lambda
  DoWork(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
}
```

If your callback needs to have something passed to it, you can use a type parameter on `Action`:

```
public static void DoWork(Action<string> processAction)
{
  // do work
  if (processAction != null)
    processAction("this is the string");
}

public static void Main()
{
  // using anonymous delegate
  DoWork(delegate(string str) { Console.WriteLine(str); });

  // using Lambda
  DoWork((str) => Console.WriteLine(str));
}
```

If it needs multiple arguments, you can add more type parameters to `Action`. If you need a return type, as mentioned use `Func` and make the return type the *last* type parameter (`Func<string, int>` is a function accepting a string and returning an int.)

More about delegates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/index?view=netframework-4.8).

### Using an interface

```
public interface IObjectWithX
{
  void X();
}

public class MyObjectWithX : IObjectWithX
{
  public void X()
  {
    // do something
  }
}

public class ActionClass
{
  public static void DoWork(IObjectWithX handlerObject)
  {
    // do work
    handlerObject.X();
  }
}

public static void Main()
{
  var obj = new MyObjectWithX()
  ActionClass.DoWork(obj);
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of expanding this excellent answer a bit in ways that would have helped me when I found it. Obviously, if you don't care for the changes, please just roll back. Thanks for the help in any case!

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a perfect recipe for delegates - in particular, callbacks with delegates are exactly how this is handled in the asynchronous pattern in .NET.

The caller would usually pass you some state and a delegate, and you store both of them in whatever context you've got, then call the delegate passing it the state and whatever result you might have.

You could either make the state just `object` or potentially use a generic delegate and take state of the appropriate type, e.g.

```
public delegate void Callback<T>(T state, OperationResult result)
```

Then:

```
public void DoSomeOperation(int otherParameterForWhateverReason,
                            Callback<T> callback, T state)
```

As you're using .NET 3.5 you might want to use the existing `Func<...>` and `Action<...>`
delegate types, but you *may* find it makes it clearer to declare your own. (The name may make it clearer what you're using it for.)

Comment: I suggest you read up on delegates then (and generics, potentially). My article on delegates and evvents is at http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html

Answer (score 1):

The object in question will need to implement an interface provided by you.  Take the interface as a parameter, and then you can call any method that the interface exposes.  Otherwise you have no way of knowing what the object is capable of.  That, or you could take a delegate as a parameter and call that.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to have your library provide a public event to be fired when the operation is complete?  Then the caller could just register to handle the event and you don't have to worry about passing around objects or delegates.

The object implementing an interface you have provided would work, but it seems to be more the Java approach than the .NET approach.  Events seem a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html to learn about events. They may or may not be appropriate for your situation, but they're worth knowing about.

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.Action available in C#.NET for callback functions.  Please check this sample example:

```
    //Say you are calling some FUNC1 that has the tight while loop and you need to 
    //get updates on what percentage the updates have been done.
    private void ExecuteUpdates()
    {
        Func1(Info => { lblUpdInfo.Text = Info; });
    }

    //Now Func1 would keep calling back the Action specified in the argument
    //This System.Action can be returned for any type by passing the Type as the template.
    //This example is returning string.
    private void Func1(System.Action<string> UpdateInfo)
    {
        int nCount = 0;
        while (nCount < 100)
        {
            nCount++;
            if (UpdateInfo != null) UpdateInfo("Counter: " + nCount.ToString());
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not an alternative to a callback; that **is** a callback.