# Multithreads Callback

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, tcpclient

so i'm trying to create a system that uses a TcpClient to send and recieve data from a server. I have a thread listening for data coming in.

What I want is to be able to make a method which can:

**Write to the stream > Wait for response > Process response**

But at the same time, other irrelevant data may also come in during this time, so I can't just do:

```
writer.WriteLine("");
string response = reader.ReadLine();
```

I was looking at 'callbacks' in this question > [Callbacks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667742/callbacks-in-c-sharp) and it seems like this is the way I need to go, but I'm not entirely sure how I can proceed with this.

Any help with this would be great, thanks!

**Edit for Jim Mischel:**

This is the sort of thing I want to achieve:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password) {
    writer.Write("{ \"username\" : \"" + username + "\", \"password\" : \"" + password + "\" }";
    //Somehow get the response which is being ran on another thread (See below)

    //Process the JSON into a object and check is successful or not 
    if (msg.result == "Ok") return true;
    else return false;
}

private void ReadThread()
{
    while (running)
    {
        if (ns.DataAvailable)
        {
            string msg = reader.ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) continue;
            Process(msg); //Process the message aka get it back to the Login method
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Basically I want to be able to call a login method which will write to a TcpClient and wait to receive a reply from the same stream and then return a boolean value.

But a basic method like so wouldn't cut it:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password) {
    writer.Write("{ \"username\" : \"" + username + "\", \"password\" : \"" + password + "\" }";
    string response = reader.ReadLine();
    if (response == "success") return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This wouldn't work because other data gets automatically pushed through the stream to me, so when waiting on the ReadLine(), I could be getting anything else instead of the response that I'm looking for.

So I'm looking for a solution which can solve this issue, currently I have a thread running which is purely for reading from the stream and then processing the message, I need to get the message from that thread over to this above method.

One way I thought about doing this is when a message gets read, for it to be put in a global List which then the Login method can be put in a loop which checks the List until the message is found within the list. But if I'm right in thinking, this is a terrible concept. So I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Can you guarantee C# 5 (.NET 4.5)? `async/await` sounds like an awesome fit for your case and it'd let you continue developing code in a synchronous way.

Comment: Was hoping .Net 4 would be the highest I'd have to go, this would be a last resort.

Comment: You can go .NET 4 as well by referencing the Microsoft.Bcl.Async Nuget package and using the C# 5 compiler.

Comment: Async/await is available for 4.0, you just need to [download it from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack).

Comment: Okay, how would I incorporate the async/await in the above example? Never used either keywords before! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I see that you just want to create a client. Much of the below is still relevant, particular the asynchronous read/write stuff in the linked answer. You can probably dig the relevant parts out of that. Or do a search for [TcpClient asynchronous example]. There are some good samples available.

The easiest way in .NET is to use [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and [BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx) to asynchronously create a connection. You can then get the network stream from the `TcpClient` and use [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) / `EndRead` and [BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginwrite.aspx) / `EndWrite` to do asynchronous reads and writes.

The linked topics have some good examples. There's a TCP Listener example here on SO somewhere . . .

Aha! Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294169/56778

Comment: This is similar to what I want sort of, look at my edited post for further explanation.